# How to show dynamic menu with multiple sitemap files?

Tags: asp.net

I want to use dynamic menu as per the user login into the system.
   I want to take multiple sitemap files with respect to user.
   Then as per the authenticated user particular sitemap should attach to StiteMapSource & then it display with the menu control on page

Reply please....
Regards,
Girish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Display menu based on login and roles is explained here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178429(VS.80).aspx

For many sitemaps: refer following examples.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/Bobum/MultipleSitemaps10242007150620PM/MultipleSitemaps.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/MutlipleSiteMap.aspx